# $\sigma$-algebra generated by $F_X (X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable and $F_X$ be its cumulative distribution function.
I am interested in the connection between the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ and that generated by $F_X (X).$
It is obvious that if $F_X$ is strictly increasing, then these coincide.
If not (i.e. $F_X$ "stays" on some interval), then just observing $F_X(X)$ does not allow you to recover $X,$ so $\sigma (F_X (X))$ cannot be greater than $\sigma (X).$
**I am wondering if there is an example where $\sigma (X)$ is strictly greater than $\sigma (F_X (X)).$**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$F_X$ is always right-continuous, so if $F_X$ is not strictly increasing it is some constant $c$ on an interval $[a,b)$.  This can only happen if $\mathbb{P}(X=a) > 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(X \in (a,b)) = 0$, so observing $F_X(X) = c$ implies $X=a$.  Therefore $\sigma(F_X(X)) = \sigma(X)$.

Comment: Even if the probability of $X$ taking values on $(a, b)$ is zero, there can be a zero-measure event where $X$ does so.

Comment: @Paruru Okay, good point.  I suppose we need the completion of $\sigma(F_X(X))$ to get equality.